# Arch Linux Arm: "error while loading shared libraries: libblas.so.3: cannot open shared object file" in Octave and R

Tags: arch-linux, libraries, arm, arch-arm

In Arch Linux Arm and Manjaro Arm, Octave and R [fail to launch](https://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=15054) with OpenBLAS 0.3.13-2. When run, it shows the error

```
error while loading shared libraries: libblas.so.3: cannot open shared object file
```

How to fix it?

Comment: I decided to post it here, so that it can be easily found via major search engines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround was first proposed in [Manjaro forum](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/arm-stable-update-2020-12-30-python-3-9-rebuilds-kernels-firefox-mesa-20-2-6-kde-apps-gstreamer-kde-frameworks-libreoffice-thunderbird-pamac/45384/33?u=archisman), and then in Arch Linux Arm [forum](https://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=15054).

One has to symlink `/usr/lib/libopenblas.so.3` with the non existent `/usr/lib/libblas.so.3`.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libopenblas.so.3 /usr/lib/libblas.so.3
```